# How does a 2 way switch with indicator work from the perspective of regular user?

Tags: switches

I see 2 way switches with indicators online, how are they different from regular two way switches without indicators? What difference does a regular user who just uses the switch to on/off will notice in these kind of switches.

What is the purpose of the indicator in the later switch? Do they glow to indicate the lamp is on? Or is it for any other purpose?

Comment: What research have you done to answer this question?

Comment: I googled about the difference, didn't find anything that answered my question concisely.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen that question here before.

Comment: @radagast I searched before posting, I didn't find any. Neither do I find anything in similar suggested questions while posting this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how are they different from regular two way switches

They have an indicator

> What difference does a regular user who just uses the switch to on/off will notice

They have an indicator

---

## Purpose of indicator

Commonly there are only two things that an indicator can indicate

- The location of a switch in darkness
- The state of a lamp in a remote location

In the UK it is common to have **different** indicators for each purpose (though either are rare)

- faint illumination around the edges of the square switchplate to indicate location in the dark
- an inset neon indicator above the rocker to confirm that the load is live.

However I'm not aware of regulations concerning this and I believe some switches have configurable indicators of the inset type that can be used for either purpose.

---

## Implications

There are implications for the wiring between switches if the indicator is to indicate the state of illumination of a remote lamp (which may be other than incandescent) - However this is not apparent *"from the perspective of a regular user"*.

---

Since this answer would be boring if I stuck to the question, I'll expand a little on the electrician's perspective.

## Two switches controlling one lamp

Here's the basic idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fstYHe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is typically wired as the topologically equivalent (but cheaper in cable costs)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWLxLI.png)</sup>

Notice that because the neutral wire doesn't reach the switch locations, you can't drive any kind of indicator with this wiring.

Here's what I believe may be typical US wiring

[image]

US colors are

- black = live / hot / phase
- white = neutral
- green = protective ground / earth
- red = "traveller"

Note that neutral is not present in the switches. The white wire has tape around the end to indicate it is being used as a switched-live conductor.

Here's typical UK wiring of a two-way switch without indicator

[image]

UK/EU colours are

- brown = live / phase
- blue = neutral
- green & yellow striped = protective earth.

Note that neutral is not present at the switches. This makes it difficult to provide any indication of lamp state.

Comment: The indicator difference is obvious by the naming, I should have added few specifics in the questions. Editing it now. Thanks :)

Comment: > However this is not apparent "from the perspective of a regular user".    

Pardon my plain language, So, if the indicator is to indicate if the lamp is on/off. Then it is for the users knowledge right? How can it be not apparent to the user?

Comment: @SathishManohar: differences in the wiring are not apparent to regular users. Regular users press switches, they don't open them up and peek at the wiring inside. The people who do that are called electricians. If you are a DIY electrician you are still not a regular user (perhaps English usage is different in your locale).

Comment: I'll try in more simpler words, Will the indicators in both 2 way switches illuminate if the circuit is closed (when the light is on?). Is that its purpose?

Comment: @SathishManohar Consider carefully what my words above actually mean : *"state of illumination of remote lamp"* - how are you interpreting that phrase?

Comment: "state of illumination of remote lamp" I interpreted these words as, okay the indicator is on when the light is on. Then upon reading 'However this is not apparent "from the perspective of a regular user".' I was lost again, I was like, how can a glowing indicator indicating something be not apparent to the user :-/ (As you might have guessed, English is not my first language :) )

Comment: It may be interesting to note that if one has a remote garage which should have a light that's switchable from the garage or the house, and one needs to have both full-time power to the garage and a light in the house that switches at the same time as the garage, the "normal" accepted approach is to use five wires from house to the garage (unswitched hot, two switched legs, switch return, and neutral), but in some places an arrangement I've read called the "California three-way" is approved to do the job with four; the C3W circuit seems dodgy to my sensibilities today...

Comment: ...though in my younger days I thought I was clever when I figured out that the scenario without the local indicator could be done with three wires even though the electrician's handbook showed four.  Later versions of the handbook coincidentally added a footnote that a "trick" version of the circuit could do the job in three wires, but did not meet code, and by the time I read that I already understood why.  I wonder if any areas have debated whether to allow the C3W approach?  As wired, it would be safe, but it could become dangerous if wiring gets changed.